# Visual Studio2017 - Productivity Power Tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way to Install Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2017 in a machine with no internet connection?

When I run ProductivityPowerPack2017.vsix file I get an error.

[image]

In the log file I found this:

```
`(...)  System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:` An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

I believe this is because my machine has limited internet connection (with some blocked URLs).

So is their a way to install Power Tools? I need Process Editor for Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Download the extension [from Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerPack2017) on another machine, copy it and install it

Comment: Can you tell me which files to copy please? And their location.

Comment: Did you check the link?

Comment: Yes. I've edit the post. Can you read it? I cannot use that file because it will try to download packages from the internet which will be blocked (I believe this is what is happening). That's why I asked how to install it in a machine whithout internet connection.

Comment: As the docs say: `This is an extension bundle installer that will install each of the individual components of Productivity Power Tools`. If you want a specific one, download it separately. There's no `Process Editor` in that list though

Comment: Than how can I install Process Editor? When I installed Power Tools usually I get the process editor option....

Comment: *What* Process Editor? The Productivity Power Tools don't contain any such tool. In fact, the entire marketplace doesn't contain any extension named that way. The closest thing is [TFS Process Template Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KarthikBalasubramanianMSFT.TFSProcessTemplateEditor), a separate tool

Comment: You are right. It TFS Process Template. However I am still not clear how to install Productivity Power Tools whithout an internet connection? Whichj i also need.

Comment: Download individual tools and install them.